# Running kotlin files in VS code terminal, kotlinc not recognized

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code, kotlinc

I want to run Kotlin code in VS Code rather than IntelliJ or any other IDE because it's the one I've been using for the longest time and I got used to it. I searched on YT and Google how to achieve this and basically, I got that I have to install the code runner extension (which I already had) and kotlinc (V 1.6). I installed the files into my Program Files folder and added the bin path to the PATH in the environment variables, tried to run the code, and got an error saying that "kotlinc is not recognized as a cmdlet". I followed the installation tutorial as is so I don't know where I went wrong when installing kotlinc. If someone has encountered this issued before and knows what the cause is or know of another way of running Kotlin in VS Code I'd be happy to know :)

Comment: Did you open new terminal session after changing environment variables? Environment variables are loaded at the beggining of terminal session so changing them requieres restartig your terminal.

Comment: yes, I also restarted my PC, and still, no changes were apparent. when I type 'kotlin' or 'kotlinc' to my terminal instead of getting a typical red-colored cmd unrecognized error I get: " 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." If I type 'java' then I get the classic red-colored cmd error and all the other mumbo jumbo

Comment: Sounds like you also need to install and configure java...

Comment: do I need a certain version for it to work properly? or would the latest one do? where do I download it from?